# Session Expiration Message on hosting multiple .Net application in IIS 7

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-7

I am facing one issue in IIS 7.

I have one custom .Net application hosted at port 80 of IIS 7.

Application 1 : https://appserver/core/pages/home.aspx

I have hosted another .Net based open source bug tracking tool (BugNet)  on App Server on port 7071.

Application 2: https://appserver:7071/bn/login.aspx

Both these application run fine on different browser, but when I login into both application on same browser, Application 1 works fine, but when I click on some links on Application 2(BugNet) it logs me out and shows me a session expiration messages.

**Session Expired

Your session has expired.  Please return to the "home page" and log in again to continue accessing your account.**

I tried several open source .Net based bug tracker to host, I installed them successfully and able to run individually, but facing the same problem when run both application on same browser.

Waiting for any hints?

Comment: Whether your applications share an application pool?

Comment: No, both the applications are having different App Pool.

Answer (score 2):

Is the Forms name value the same in the web.config file? This can cause this issue:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".MAKE SURE IT IS DIFFERENT" loginUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="60" path="/">
            </forms>
        </authentication>
```

Comment: Yes, both the application are having different form name value.